# How to detect client-side if the server disconnects me?

Tags: wcf, callback, notify, net.tcp, disconnect

I have a WCF self-hosted service with a net.tcp DuplexChannel. On the server I run the following to disconnect a client:

```
((ICommunicationObject)client.CallbackChannel).Close();
```

This works fine but how do I detect on the client that it has been disconnected?

Ive hooked up to Closed and Faulted-events on both the InstanceContext of the callback and the channel to the server:

```
InstanceContext callback = new InstanceContext(callbackImp);
callback.Closed += new EventHandler(callback_Closed);
```

and

```
((ICommunicationObject)Channel).Closed += new EventHandler(Channel_Closed);
```

But nothing works. I never get notified. The workaround Im using now is to have a method in the callback that triggers a disconnect from the client-side instead. But I rather not do it this way. I especially dont want to let the server wait for a user to disconnect.

**EDIT**

I just realized that when disconnecting from client-side I run a method in the service-contract which is marked with IsTerminating = true:

```
[OperationContract(IsTerminating = true)]
void Disconnect();
```

I figured it would be the same on the callback-contract then? I tried adding the same method to my callback and it did terminate the callback-channel from the server point of view but I still didnt got notified on the client-side...weird

**EDIT**

I found out some more info about this:

> When the server aborts the callback
>   channel, a fault travels back to the
>   client, the client faults and we get
>   the Faulted event on the client.
>
> When the server closes the callback
>   channel, the session is still open
>   until the client issues the close.
>
> Once the client closes the channel
>   you'll see the Closed event.

According to this statement the Close-event is not triggered mearly by closing the callbackchannel from the server, the client has to close it as well. So I could run Close on the client in the terminating Disconnect-method of the callback. Or I could use the Abort-method on the callback server-side and skip using a Disconnect-method on the callback. I dont know which one I preffer honestly. Hmmmm.

**EDIT**

I went with the Abort-approach. It seemed like the most logical method and it works really well. The client gets notified with the Faulted-event on the callback-instancecontext. Nice.

Comment: look at this I have same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986347/wcf-duplex-retrieve-client-connection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went with the Abort-approach. It seemed like the most logical method and it works really well. The client gets notified with the Faulted-event on the callback-instancecontext.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do a callback just before closing the callback channel telling the client you're closing the channel.

So just before this line of code:

```
((ICommunicationObject)client.CallbackChannel).Close();
```

Comment: how about providing some more details about what doesn't work.... I know it works as there is some prod software out there running code using the callbackchannel. Don't recall exact implementation as it was 6 years ago, but imho, just saying it doesn't work and downvoting the answer is a bit childish.

Comment: The edits in the question explain it, closing the callback won't notify the client of it. You have to abort it so that the client receives the faulted event.